# Can tern complete for methods in React extended classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, tern, ternjs

If I'm extending a `React.Component` eg.

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constr// with point here, can this complete "constructor"
}
```

is it possible to get completions for the `React.Component` methods eg. `constructor`?

My current ~/.tern-config  does enable the react lib, eg.

```
{
    "libs": [
        "react",
        // etc.
     ],
     // etc.
}
```

which does give doc/url info for `React.Component`, but doesn't complete for the methods.  I've read through a fair amount of the tern documentation, but can't determine if this should be supported or not.

Comment: If you create the app with create-react-app this can help: https://medium.com/@jrwillette88/tern-why-it-breaks-and-how-to-fix-it-8d1677df05f9

Comment: @FranciscoPuga thanks, that looks like it might solve the problem